# Multiple columns poetry, 4 parallel poems

Tags: verse

I want an A3 paper size output with 4 parallel poems; three of them are actually the translations of the first one. How can I do it?

```
    \documentclass[
12pt,
oneside,
landscape
]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguages{english,portuguese}

\usepackage{libertine} 


\usepackage{verse}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    paper=a3paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    inner=20mm, % Inner margin
    outer=20mm, % Outer margin
    top=20mm, % Top margin
    bottom=20mm, % Bottom margin
}


\title{\Huge{\textbf{Inferno I}}}
\author{\huge{Dante Alighieri}}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle

%italian
\poemtitle{Italiano}
\settowidth{\versewidth}{sì che 'l piè fermo sempre era 'l più basso.}\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
    \poemlines{3}
    \indentpattern{011}
    \begin{patverse*}
        Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita\\
        mi ritrovai per una selva oscura,\\
        ché la diritta via era smarrita.\\
        Ahi quanto a dir qual era è cosa dura\\
        esta selva selvaggia e aspra e forte\\
        che nel pensier rinova la paura!\\
        Tant' è amara che poco è più morte;\\
        ma per trattar del ben ch'i' vi trovai,\\
        dirò de l'altre cose ch'i' v'ho scorte.\\
        Io non so ben ridir com' i' v'intrai,\\
        tant' era pien di sonno a quel punto\\
        che la verace via abbandonai.\\
        Ma poi ch'i' fui al piè d'un colle giunto,\\
        là dove terminava quella valle\\
        che m'avea di paura il cor compunto,\\
        guardai in alto e vidi le sue spalle\\
        vestite già de' raggi del pianeta\\
        che mena dritto altrui per ogne calle.\\
        Allor fu la paura un poco queta,\\
        che nel lago del cor m'era durata\\
        la notte ch'i' passai con tanta pieta.\\
        E come quei che con lena affannata,\\
        uscito fuor del pelago a la riva,\\
        si volge a l'acqua perigliosa e guata,\\
        così l'animo mio, ch'ancor fuggiva,\\
        si volse a retro a rimirar lo passo\\
        che non lasciò già mai persona viva.\\
        Poi ch'èi posato un poco il corpo lasso,\\
        ripresi via per la piaggia diserta,\\
        sì che 'l piè fermo sempre era 'l più basso.\\
        Ed ecco, quasi al cominciar de l'erta,\\
        una lonza leggiera e presta molto,\\
        che di pel macolato era coverta;\\
        e non mi si partia dinanzi al volto,\\
        anzi 'mpediva tanto il mio cammino,\\
        ch'i' fui per ritornar più volte vòlto.\\
        Temp' era dal principio del mattino,\\
        e 'l sol montava 'n sù con quelle stelle\\
        ch'eran con lui quando l'amor divino\\
        mosse di prima quelle cose belle;\\
        sì ch'a bene sperar m'era cagione\\
        di quella fiera a la gaetta pelle\\
        l'ora del tempo e la dolce stagione;\\
        ma non sì che paura non mi desse\\
        la vista che m'apparve d'un leone.\\
        Questi parea che contra me venisse\\
        con la test' alta e con rabbiosa fame,\\
        sì che parea che l'aere ne tremesse.\\
        Ed una lupa, che di tutte brame\\
        sembiava carca ne la sua magrezza,\\
        e molte genti fé già viver grame,\\
        questa mi porse tanto di gravezza\\
        con la paura ch'uscia di sua vista,\\
        ch'io perdei la speranza de l'altezza.\\
        E qual è quei che volontieri acquista,\\
        e giugne 'l tempo che perder lo face,\\
        che 'n tutti suoi pensier piange e s'attrista;\\
        tal mi fece la bestia sanza pace,\\
        che, venendomi 'ncontro, a poco a poco\\
        mi ripigneva là dove 'l sol tace.\\
        Mentre ch'i' rovinava in basso loco,\\
        dinanzi a li occhi mi si fu offerto\\
        chi per lungo silenzio parea fioco.\\
        Quando vidi costui nel gran diserto,\\
        «Miserere di me», gridai a lui,\\
        «qual che tu sii, od ombra od omo certo!».\\
        Rispuosemi: «Non omo, omo già fui,\\
        e li parenti miei furon lombardi,\\
        mantoani per patrïa ambedui.\\
        Nacqui sub Iulio, ancor che fosse tardi,\\
        e vissi a Roma sotto 'l buono Augusto\\
        nel tempo de li dèi falsi e bugiardi.\\
        Poeta fui, e cantai di quel giusto\\
        figliuol d'Anchise che venne di Troia,\\
        poi che 'l superbo Ilïón fu combusto.\\
        Ma tu perché ritorni a tanta noia?\\
        perché non sali il dilettoso monte\\
        ch'è principio e cagion di tutta gioia?».\\
        «Or se' tu quel Virgilio e quella fonte\\
        che spandi di parlar sì largo fiume?»,\\
        rispuos' io lui con vergognosa fronte.\\
        «O de li altri poeti onore e lume,\\
        vagliami 'l lungo studio e 'l grande amore\\
        che m'ha fatto cercar lo tuo volume.\\
        Tu se' lo mio maestro e 'l mio autore,\\
        tu se' solo colui da cu' io tolsi\\
        lo bello stilo che m'ha fatto onore.\\
        Vedi la bestia per cu' io mi volsi;\\
        aiutami da lei, famoso saggio,\\
        ch'ella mi fa tremar le vene e i polsi».\\
        «A te convien tenere altro vïaggio»,\\
        rispuose, poi che lagrimar mi vide,\\
        «se vuo' campar d'esto loco selvaggio;\\
        ché questa bestia, per la qual tu gride,\\
        non lascia altrui passar per la sua via,\\
        ma tanto lo 'mpedisce che l'uccide;\\
        e ha natura sì malvagia e ria,\\
        che mai non empie la bramosa voglia,\\
        e dopo 'l pasto ha più fame che pria.\\
        Molti son li animali a cui s'ammoglia,\\
        e più saranno ancora, infin che 'l veltro\\
        verrà, che la farà morir con doglia.\\
        Questi non ciberà terra né peltro,\\
        ma sapïenza, amore e virtute,\\
        e sua nazion sarà tra feltro e feltro.\\
        Di quella umile Italia fia salute\\
        per cui morì la vergine Cammilla,\\
        Eurialo e Turno e Niso di ferute.\\
        Questi la caccerà per ogne villa,\\
        fin che l'avrà rimessa ne lo 'nferno,\\
        là onde 'nvidia prima dipartilla.\\
        Ond' io per lo tuo me' penso e discerno\\
        che tu mi segui, e io sarò tua guida,\\
        e trarrotti di qui per loco etterno;\\
        ove udirai le disperate strida,\\
        vedrai li antichi spiriti dolenti,\\
        ch'a la seconda morte ciascun grida;\\
        e vederai color che son contenti\\
        nel foco, perché speran di venire\\
        quando che sia a le beate genti.\\
        A le quai poi se tu vorrai salire,\\
        anima fia a ciò più di me degna:\\
        con lei ti lascerò nel mio partire;\\
        ché quello imperador che là sù regna,\\
        perch' i' fu' ribellante a la sua legge,\\
        non vuol che 'n sua città per me si vegna.\\
        In tutte parti impera e quivi regge;\\
        quivi è la sua città e l'alto seggio:\\
        oh felice colui cu' ivi elegge!».\\
        E io a lui: «Poeta, io ti richeggio\\
        per quello Dio che tu non conoscesti,\\
        a ciò ch'io fugga questo male e peggio,\\
        che tu mi meni là dov' or dicesti,\\
        sì ch'io veggia la porta di san Pietro\\
        e color cui tu fai cotanto mesti».\\
        Allor si mosse, e io li tenni dietro.
    \end{patverse*}
\end{verse}

\poemtitle{English}
\settowidth{\versewidth}{Thou wouldst conduct me there where thou hast said,}\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
    \poemlines{3}
    \indentpattern{011}
    \begin{patverse*}
MIDWAY upon the journey of our life\\
I found myself within a forest dark,\\
⁠For the straightforward pathway had been lost.\\
Ah me! how hard a thing it is to say\\
⁠What was this forest savage, rough, and stern, \\
⁠Which in the very thought renews the fear.\\
So bitter is it, death is little more;\\
⁠But of the good to treat, which there I found,\\
⁠Speak will I of the other things I saw there.\\
I cannot well repeat how there I entered, ⁠\\
⁠So full was I of slumber at the moment\\
⁠In which I had abandoned the true way.\\
But after I had reached a mountain's foot,\\
⁠At that point where the valley terminated,\\
⁠Which had with consternation pierced my heart, ⁠\\
Upward I looked, and I beheld its shoulders,\\
⁠Vested already with that planet's rays\\
⁠Which leadeth others right by every road.\\
Then was the fear a little quieted\\
⁠That in my heart's lake had endured throughout ⁠\\
⁠The night, which I had passed so piteously.\\
And even as he, who, with distressful breath,\\
⁠Forth issued from the sea upon the shore,\\
⁠Turns to the water perilous and gazes;\\
So did my soul, that still was fleeing onward, \\
⁠Turn itself back to re-behold the pass\\
⁠Which never yet a living person left.\\
After my weary body I had rested,\\
⁠The way resumed I on the desert slope,\\
⁠So that the firm foot ever was the lower. ⁠\\
And lo! almost where the ascent began,\\
⁠A panther light and swift exceedingly,\\
⁠Which with a spotted skin was covered o'er!\\
And never moved she from before my face,\\
⁠Nay, rather did impede so much my way, ⁠\\
⁠That many times I to return had turned.\\
The time was the beginning of the morning,\\
⁠And up the sun was mounting with those stars\\
⁠That with him were, what time the Love Divine\\
At first in motion set those beauteous things; ⁠\\
⁠So were to me occasion of good hope,\\
⁠The variegated skin of that wild beast,\\
The hour of time, and the delicious season;\\
⁠But not so much, that did not give me fear\\
⁠A lion's aspect which appeared to me. ⁠\\
He seemed as if against me he were coming\\
⁠With head uplifted, and with ravenous hunger,\\
⁠So that it seemed the air was afraid of him;\\
And a she-wolf, that with all hungerings\\
⁠Seemed to be laden in her meagreness, ⁠\\
⁠And many folk has caused to live forlorn!\\
She brought upon me so much heaviness,\\
⁠With the affright that from her aspect came,\\
⁠That I the hope relinquished of the height.\\
And as he is who willingly acquires, \\
⁠And the time comes that causes him to lose,\\
⁠Who weeps in all his thoughts and is despondent,\\
E'en such made me that beast withouten peace,\\
⁠Which, coming on against me by degrees,\\
⁠Thrust me back thither where the sun is silent. \\
While I was rushing downward to the lowland,\\
⁠Before mine eyes did one present himself,\\
⁠Who seemed from long-continued silence hoarse.\\
When I beheld him in the desert vast,\\
⁠"Have pity on me," unto him I cried, ⁠\\
⁠"Whiche'er thou art, or shade or real man!"\\
He answered me: "Not man; man once I was,\\
⁠And both my parents were of Lombardy,\\
⁠And Mantuans by country both of them.\\
Sub Julio was I born, though it was late, \\
⁠And lived at Rome under the good Augustus,\\
⁠During the time of false and lying gods.\\
A Poet was I, and I sang that just\\
⁠Son of Anchises, who came forth from Troy,\\
⁠After that Ilion the superb was burned. \\
But thou, why goest thou back to such annoyance?\\
⁠Why climb'st thou not the Mount Delectable,\\
⁠Which is the source and cause of every joy?"\\
"Now, art thou that Virgilius and that fountain\\
⁠Which spreads abroad so wide a river of speech?" ⁠\\
⁠I made response to him with bashful forehead.\\
"O, of the other poets honor and light,\\
⁠Avail me the long study and great love\\
⁠That have impelled me to explore thy volume!\\
Thou art my master, and my author thou, ⁠\\
⁠Thou art alone the one from whom I took\\
⁠The beautiful style that has done honor to me.\\
Behold the beast, for which I have turned back;\\
⁠Do thou protect me from her, famous Sage,\\
⁠For she doth make my veins and pulses tremble."\\
"Thee it behoves to take another road,"\\
⁠Responded he, when he beheld me weeping,\\
⁠"If from this savage place thou wouldst escape;\\
Because this beast, at which thou criest out,\\
⁠Suffers not any one to pass her way, ⁠\\
⁠But so doth harass him, that she destroys him;\\
And has a nature so malign and ruthless,\\
⁠That never doth she glut her greedy will,\\
⁠And after food is hungrier than before.\\
Many the animals with whom she weds, ⁠\\
⁠And more they shall be still, until the Greyhound\\
⁠Comes, who shall make her perish in her pain.\\
He shall not feed on either earth or pelf,\\
⁠But upon wisdom, and on love and virtue;\\
⁠'Twixt Feltro and Feltro shall his nation be; ⁠\\
Of that low Italy shall he be the saviour,\\
⁠On whose account the maid Camilla died,\\
⁠Euryalus, Turnus, Nisus, of their wounds;\\
Through every city shall he hunt her down,\\
⁠Until he shall have driven her back to Hell, ⁠\\
⁠There from whence envy first did let her loose.\\
Therefore I think and judge it for thy best\\
⁠Thou follow me, and I will be thy guide,\\
⁠And lead thee hence through the eternal place,\\
Where thou shalt hear the desperate lamentations, \\
⁠Shalt see the ancient spirits disconsolate,\\
⁠Who cry out each one for the second death;\\
And thou shalt see those who contented are\\
⁠Within the fire, because they hope to come,\\
⁠Whene'er it may be, to the blessed people; ⁠\\
To whom, then, if thou wishest to ascend,\\
⁠A soul shall be for that than I more worthy;\\
⁠With her at my departure I will leave thee;\\
Because that Emperor, who reigns above,\\
⁠In that I was rebellious to his law, ⁠\\
⁠Wills that through me none come into his city.\\
He governs everywhere, and there he reigns;\\
⁠There is his city and his lofty throne;\\
⁠O happy he whom thereto he elects!"\\
And I to him: "Poet, I thee entreat, ⁠\\
⁠By that same God whom thou didst never know,\\
⁠So that I may escape this woe and worse,\\
Thou wouldst conduct me there where thou hast said,\\
⁠That I may see the portal of Saint Peter,\\
⁠And those thou makest so disconsolate." ⁠\\
Then he moved on, and I behind him followed.    \end{patverse*}
\end{verse}

%Ligurian
\poemtitle{Ligurian}
\settowidth{\versewidth}{ò ammiòu sciù in èrto e ò visto allôa e sêu spalle}\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
    \poemlines{3}
    \indentpattern{011}
    \begin{patverse*}
        A-o mëzo do cammin da nòstra vitta\\
        me so' attrovòu inte na forèsta scüa,\\
        perdendo a strâ che a-o ben l'òmmo a tragitta.\\
        Quanto, a dî comme a l'ëa, l'è còsa düa,\\
        sta forèsta sarvæga e àspia e fòrte,\\
        che a ripensâla ancon poïa a me procüa\\
        Tanto a l'è amäa che no goæi ciù l'è a mòrte\\
        ma, pe trattâ do ben che gh'ò attrovòu,\\
        de l'âtro ò visto e l'è ben che ô ripòrte.\\
        Mi no sò ben dî comme ghe so' intròu,\\
        tanto mi ëo pin de seunno in quòu momento\\
        che o vëo cammin avéivo abbandonòu.\\
        Ma quande a-i pê de na montâ a gran stento\\
        mi so' arrivòu, dove finiva a valle\\
        che into chêu a m'aiva misso un gran spavento,\\
        ò ammiòu sciù in èrto e ò visto allôa e sêu spalle\\
        dezzâ vestïe di raggi do pianeta\\
        che o guidda drïto e o fâ che no se falle.\\
        Allôa s'è fæto a poïa un pö ciù queta,\\
        che into lago do chêu a m'ëa düâ\\
        a-a neutte che a l'ëa stæta coscì inquieta.\\
        E comme chi con fadiga affannâ,\\
        sciortïo de fëua da-o mâ gròsso insce a riva\\
        l'ægua peigosa o se regïa li a ammiâ,\\
        coscì l'animo mæ, che anco' o corriva,\\
        o s'è regiòu inderrê a ammiâ quello passo\\
        che o no l'à mai lasciòu personn-a viva.\\
        Dòppo ësime pôsòu da-o gran strapasso,\\
        ò repiggiòu a montâ a riva desèrta,\\
        coscì che àivo o pê fèrmo sempre in basso.\\
        Quande, a-o prinçipio da montâ ò scovèrta\\
        na lonza lëgia e bèll'e pronta a-a caccia,\\
        che de péi tùtto a macce a l'ëa covèrta;\\
        e a no voéiva scostâse da-a mæ faccia,\\
        ansi, a impediva tanto o mæ cammin,\\
        che m'ëo za giòu pe tornâ insce a mæ traccia.\\
        L'ëa o tempo insce o prinçipio do mattin,\\
        e o sô o montava sciù con quelle stelle\\
        che i l'ëan con lê quande l'Amô divin\\
        o l'à inissiòu a mesciâ quæ còse bèlle;\\
        coscì che a ben sperâ àivo raxon\\
        de quella fëa con tùtte e macce a-a pelle\\
        da l'ôa do tempo e da-a dôçe stagion;\\
        ma no coscì che poïa a no me desse\\
        a brùtta vista che ò avüo de un leon.\\
        Me pàiva contra a mì che o se mescesse\\
        con a testa äta e tanta raggia e famme,\\
        che pàiva che anche l'äia a ne tremmesse.\\
        E 'na lôa ò visto tùtta òsse e pellamme,\\
        d'ògni coæ càrega inta sêu magressa,\\
        che tanta gente a l'à fæto stâ gramme;\\
        questa a m'à dæto li tanta amaressa\\
        con a poïa che a sciortiva da-a sêu vista,\\
        che ò perso a speànsa de montâ in altessa.\\
        E comme un che, fæta 'na conquista,\\
        vegne o tempo ch'o a pèrde e o se despiaxe,\\
        e in tùtti i sêu penscëi o se rattrista;\\
        pægio m'à fæto a bestia sensa paxe,\\
        che, vegnindome incontro, a me sponciava\\
        cianin cianin lazzù dove o sô o taxe.\\
        Intanto che zù in basso mi derruava,\\
        davanti a-i euggi me se gh'è li òffèrto\\
        chi pe-o silensio röco o o se mostrava\\
        Quande l'ò visto inte quòu gran desèrto,\\
        "Miserere de mì", criando gh'ò fæto,\\
        "che ti seggi 'n'ombra ò 'n òmmo çèrto!"\\
        "No son un òmmo, ma òmmo son stæto",\\
        o m'à dïto, "e i mæ pænti i l'ëan lombardi,\\
        e a l'è Màntoa che a nascion a gh'à dæto.\\
        Nasciüo sub Julio, anche se un pö tardi,\\
        son visciüo a Romma sotto o bon Augusto\\
        a-o tempo che gh'ëa i dèi fäsi e boxardi\\
        Son stæto un poeta, e ò cantòu quello giusto\\
        figgio d'Anchise vegnüo via da Tròia,\\
        dòppo che a l'ëa brüxâ inte 'n gran trambusto.\\
        Ma ti perchè ti torni a tanta nòia,\\
        e no ti væ insce o mäveggiôso monte\\
        che o l'è prinçipio e caxon de ògni giòia?"\\
        "T'è pròpio ti o Virgiglio e quella fonte\\
        che de parlâ ti spandi un largo sciumme?",\\
        gh'ò rispòsto con vergognôsa fronte.\\
        "Ti che ti è di ätri poeti ònô e lumme,\\
        conscìdera o gran studdio e o grande amô\\
        che o m'à fæto riçercâ o têu volumme.\\
        Ti ti è o mæ méistro, ti ti è o mæ autô,\\
        ti è sôlo ti quello da-o quæ ò piggiòu\\
        quòu bèllo stile che o m'à fæto ònô.\\
        Ammïa a bestia pe-a quæ me son regiòu;\\
        aggiùttime, sävio degno de òmàggio,\\
        che pe lê e venn-e e i pösi i m'an tremmòu."\\
        "A ti convegne tegnî 'n ätro viaggio",\\
        ò fà a mì che cianzéivo a tésta bassa,\\
        "se t'êu scampâ da sto grammo passaggio;\\
        perchè t'æ da savéi che sta bestiassa\\
        nisciun a lascia passâ pe-a sêu strâ,\\
        ma tanto a l'impedisce che a l'ammassa;\\
        e a l'à in sè 'na natüa coscì despiâ,\\
        cha a no soddisfa mai a sêu coæ bramosa,\\
        e dòppo avéi mangiòu a no è mai soulâ.\\
        Tante so' e bestie co-e quæ lê a se sposa,\\
        e ciù tante i saiàn, fin quande un vèltro\\
        vegnâ a dâghe 'na mòrte dolorosa.\\
        Questo o no se nutriâ de tæra ò pèltro\\
        ma de virtù, de sæximo e d'amô,\\
        e a nascion o l'aviâ tra fèltro e fèltro.\\
        De quell'Itaglia o saiâ o salvatô\\
        pe-a quæ l'è mòrta a vèrgine Camilla,\\
        e Eurialo e Turno e Niso, con valô.\\
        Questo o ghe daiâ a caccia pe ògni villa,\\
        finchè o l'aviâ rimissa inte l'infèrno,\\
        donde inviddia a partî gh'à allentòu a brilla.\\
        Pe-o têu bén questo allôa mi penso e çèrno\\
        che ti me segui, fàndote guiddâ,\\
        pe portâte da chi inte un pòsto etèrno\\
        dove i despiæ ti î sentiæ cianze e luâ,\\
        e ti veddiæ i spïti antighi dolénti\\
        che a 'na segonda mòrte i stan a criâ;\\
        e di ätri ti veddiæ che i stan contenti\\
        into feugo, sperando de vegnî\\
        ò primma ò dòppo fra e beate genti.\\
        Se pòi a montâ ciù in sciù t'êu proseguî,\\
        'n'ànima ghe saiâ de mì ciù degna:\\
        con lê mì te lasciö into mæ partî;\\
        perchè l'imperatô che lasciù o regna,\\
        essendo stæto ribèlle a-a sêu lezze,\\
        che pòsse intrâ inta sêu çittæ o disdegna.\\
        Dappertùtto o l'impera e anche là o rezze;\\
        lasciù gh'è a sêu çittæ e l'äto scanno:\\
        òh feliçe chi a stâ con lê o l'elezze!"\\
        E a lê: "Poeta", diggo pin d'affanno,\\
        "pe-o Dio da ti no conosciüo te invito,\\
        perchè da-o mâ me scampe e da ògni danno,\\
        a portâme con ti dove t'æ dïto,\\
        coscì che vedde a pòrta de San Pê\\
        e quelli che en despiæ inte un tristo scito."\\
        Lê o s'è mesciòu, e ghe so' andæto derrê.
    \end{patverse*}
\end{verse}

\poemtitle{Portuguese}
\settowidth{\versewidth}{“Quem quer que sejas, sombra ou homem certo!”}\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
    \poemlines{3}
    \indentpattern{011}
    \begin{patverse*}
        Da nossa vida, em meio da jornada,\\
        Achei-me numa selva tenebrosa,\\
        Tendo perdido a verdadeira estrada.\\
        Dizer qual era é cousa tão penosa,\\
        Desta brava espessura a asperidade,\\
        Que a memória a relembra inda cuidosa.\\
        Na morte há pouco mais de acerbidade;\\
        Mas para o bem narrar lá deparado\\
        De outras cousas que vi, direi verdade.\\
        Contar não posso como tinha entrado;\\
        Tanto o sono os sentidos me tomara,\\
        Quando hei o bom caminho abandonado.\\
        Depois que a uma colina me cercara,\\
        Onde ia o vale escuro terminando,\\
        Que pavor tão profundo me causara.\\
        Ao alto olhei, e já, de luz banhando,\\
        Vi-lhe estar às espaldas o planeta,\\
        Que, certo, em toda parte vai guiando.\\
        Então o assombro um tanto se aquieta,\\
        Que do peito no lago perdurava,\\
        Naquela noite atribulada, inquieta.\\
        E como quem o anélito esgotava\\
        Sobre as ondas, já salvo, inda medroso\\
        Olha o mar perigoso em que lutava,\\
        O meu ânimo assim, que treme ansioso,\\
        Volveu-se a remirar vencido o espaço\\
        Que homem vivo jamais passou ditoso.\\
        Tendo já repousado o corpo lasso,\\
        Segui pela deserta falda avante;\\
        Mais baixo sendo o pé firme no passo.\\
        Eis da subida quase ao mesmo instante\\
        Assoma ágil e rápida pantera\\
        Tendo a pele por malhas cambiante.\\
        Não se afastava de ante mim a fera;\\
        E em modo tal meu caminhar tolhia,\\
        Que atrás por vezes eu tornar quisera.\\
        No céu a aurora já resplandecia,\\
        Subia o sol, dos astros rodeado,\\
        Seus sócios, quando o Amor divino um dia\\
        A tais primores movimento há dado.\\
        Me infundiam desta arte alma esperança\\
        Da fera o dorso alegre e mosqueado,\\
        A hora amena e a quadra doce e mansa.\\
        De um leão de repente surge o aspecto,\\
        Que ao meu peito o pavor de novo lança.\\
        Que me investisse então cuido inquieto;\\
        Com fome e raiva atroz fronte levanta;\\
        Tremer parece o ar ao seu conspeto.\\
        Eis surge loba, que de magra espanta;\\
        De ambições todas parecia cheia;\\
        Foi causa a muitos de miséria tanta!\\
        Com tanta intensa torvação me enleia\\
        Pelo terror, que o cenho seu movia,\\
        Que a mente à altura não subir receia.\\
        Como quem lucro anela noite e dia,\\
        Se acaso o tempo de perder lhe chega,\\
        Rebenta em pranto e triste se excrucia.\\
        A fera assim me fez, que não sossega;\\
        Pouco a pouco me investe até lançar-me\\
        Lá onde o sol se cala e a luz me nega.\\
        Quando ao vale eu já ia baquear-me\\
        Alguém fraco de voz diviso perto,\\
        Que após largo silêncio quer falar-me.\\
        Tanto que o vejo nesse grão deserto,\\
        — “Tem compaixão de mim” — bradei transido —\\
        “Quem quer que sejas, sombra ou homem certo!”\\
        “Homem não sou” tornou-me — “mas hei sido,\\
        Pais lombardos eu tive; sempre amada\\
        Mântua lhes foi; haviam lá nascido.\\
        “Nasci de Júlio em era retardada,\\
        Vivi em Roma sob o bom Augusto,\\
        Quando em deuses havia a crença errada.\\
        “Poeta, decantei feitos do justo\\
        Filho de Anquíses, que de Tróia veio,\\
        Depois que Ílion soberbo foi combusto.\\
        “Mas por que tornas da tristeza ao meio?\\
        Por que não vais ao deleitoso monte,\\
        Que o prazer todo encerra no seu seio?”\\
        “— Oh! Virgílio, tu és aquela fonte\\
        Donde em rio caudal brota a eloqüência?”\\
        Falei, curvando vergonhoso a fronte. —\\
        “Ó dos poetas lustre, honra, eminência!\\
        Valham-me o longo estudo, o amor profundo\\
        Com que em teu livro procurei ciência!\\
        “És meu mestre, o modelo sem segundo;\\
        Unicamente és tu que hás-me ensinado;\\
        O belo estilo que honra-me no mundo.\\
        “A fera vês que o passo me há vedado;\\
        Sábio famoso, acude ao perseguido!\\
        Tremo no pulso e veias, transtornado!”\\
        Respondeu, do meu pranto condoído;\\
        “Te convém outra rota de ora avante\\
        Para o lugar selvagem ser vencido.\\
        “A fera, que te faz bradar tremante,\\
        Aqui passar não deixa impunemente;\\
        Tanto se opõe, que mata o caminhante.\\
        “Tem tão má natureza, é tão furente,\\
        Que os apetites seus jamais sacia,\\
        E fome, impando, mais que de antes sente.\\
        “Com muitos animais se consorcia,\\
        Há-de a outros se unir té ser chegado\\
        Lebréu, que a leve à hórrida agonia.\\
        “Por ouro ou por poder nunca tentado\\
        Saber, virtude, amor terá por norte,\\
        Sendo entre Feltro e Feltro potentado.\\
        “Será da humilde Itália amparo forte,\\
        Por quem Camila a virgem dera a vida,\\
        Turno Eurialo, Niso acharam morte.\\
        “Por ele, em toda parte, repelida\\
        Irá lançar-se no infernal assento,\\
        Donde foi pela Inveja conduzida.\\
        “Agora, por teu prol, eu tenho o intento\\
        De levar-te comigo; ir-te-ei guiando\\
        Pela estância do eterno sofrimento,\\
        “Onde, estridentes gritos escutando,\\
        Verás almas antigas em tortura\\
        Segunda morte a brados suplicando.\\
        “Outros ledos verás, que, em prova dura\\
        Das chamas, inda esperam ter o gozo\\
        De Deus no prêmio da imortal ventura.\\
        “Se lá subir quiseres, um ditoso\\
        Espírito, melhor te será guia,\\
        Quando eu deixar-te, ao reino glorioso.\\
        “Do céu o Imperador, a rebeldia\\
        Minha à lei castigando, não consente\\
        Que eu da cidade sua haja a alegria.\\
        “Em toda parte impera onipotente,\\
        Mas tem no Empíreo sua augusta sede:\\
        Feliz, por ele, o eleito à glória ingente!”\\
        — “Vate, rogo-te” — eu disse — “me concede,\\
        Por esse Deus, que nunca hás conhecido,\\
        Porque este e maior mal de mim se arrede.\\
        “Que, até onde disseste conduzido,\\
        À porta de São Pedro eu vá contigo\\
        E veja os maus que houveste referido”.\\
        Move-se o Vate então, após o sigo.
    \end{patverse*}
\end{verse}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by using the package `paracol`.

`\begin{paracol}{4}` starts 4 columns of equal width.

`\switchcolumn`  switch to the next column.

`\setcolumnwidth{...}` allows to set the columns  width and the gap in between.

[image: b]

```
 \documentclass[
12pt,
oneside,
landscape
]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguages{english,portuguese}

\usepackage{libertine}  

\usepackage{verse}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    paper=a3paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    inner=20mm, % Inner margin
    outer=20mm, % Outer margin
    top=20mm, % Top margin
    bottom=20mm, % Bottom margin
}

\usepackage{paracol} % added <<<<<
\parindent=0pt

\title{\Huge{\textbf{Inferno I}}}
\author{\huge{Dante Alighieri}}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
\setcolumnwidth{0.2\textwidth/20pt, 0.25\textwidth/20pt,0.24\textwidth/20pt,0.22\textwidth}

    \begin{paracol}{4}% added <<<<<
    %italian
    \poemtitle{Italiano}
    \settowidth{\versewidth}{sì che 'l piè fermo sempre era 'l più basso.}\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
        \poemlines{3}
        \indentpattern{011}
        \begin{patverse*}
            Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita\\
            mi ritrovai per una selva oscura,\\
            ché la diritta via era smarrita.\\
            Ahi quanto a dir qual era è cosa dura\\
            esta selva selvaggia e aspra e forte\\
            che nel pensier rinova la paura!\\
            Tant' è amara che poco è più morte;\\
            ma per trattar del ben ch'i' vi trovai,\\
            dirò de l'altre cose ch'i' v'ho scorte.\\
            Io non so ben ridir com' i' v'intrai,\\
            tant' era pien di sonno a quel punto\\
            che la verace via abbandonai.\\
            Ma poi ch'i' fui al piè d'un colle giunto,\\
            là dove terminava quella valle\\
            che m'avea di paura il cor compunto,\\
            guardai in alto e vidi le sue spalle\\
            vestite già de' raggi del pianeta\\
            che mena dritto altrui per ogne calle.\\
            Allor fu la paura un poco queta,\\
            che nel lago del cor m'era durata\\
            la notte ch'i' passai con tanta pieta.\\
            E come quei che con lena affannata,\\
            uscito fuor del pelago a la riva,\\
            si volge a l'acqua perigliosa e guata,\\
            così l'animo mio, ch'ancor fuggiva,\\
            si volse a retro a rimirar lo passo\\
            che non lasciò già mai persona viva.\\
            Poi ch'èi posato un poco il corpo lasso,\\
            ripresi via per la piaggia diserta,\\
            sì che 'l piè fermo sempre era 'l più basso.\\
            Ed ecco, quasi al cominciar de l'erta,\\
            una lonza leggiera e presta molto,\\
            che di pel macolato era coverta;\\
            e non mi si partia dinanzi al volto,\\
            anzi 'mpediva tanto il mio cammino,\\
            ch'i' fui per ritornar più volte vòlto.\\
            Temp' era dal principio del mattino,\\
            e 'l sol montava 'n sù con quelle stelle\\
            ch'eran con lui quando l'amor divino\\
            mosse di prima quelle cose belle;\\
            sì ch'a bene sperar m'era cagione\\
            di quella fiera a la gaetta pelle\\
            l'ora del tempo e la dolce stagione;\\
            ma non sì che paura non mi desse\\
            la vista che m'apparve d'un leone.\\
            Questi parea che contra me venisse\\
            con la test' alta e con rabbiosa fame,\\
            sì che parea che l'aere ne tremesse.\\
            Ed una lupa, che di tutte brame\\
            sembiava carca ne la sua magrezza,\\
            e molte genti fé già viver grame,\\
            questa mi porse tanto di gravezza\\
            con la paura ch'uscia di sua vista,\\
            ch'io perdei la speranza de l'altezza.\\
            E qual è quei che volontieri acquista,\\
            e giugne 'l tempo che perder lo face,\\
            che 'n tutti suoi pensier piange e s'attrista;\\
            tal mi fece la bestia sanza pace,\\
            che, venendomi 'ncontro, a poco a poco\\
            mi ripigneva là dove 'l sol tace.\\
            Mentre ch'i' rovinava in basso loco,\\
            dinanzi a li occhi mi si fu offerto\\
            chi per lungo silenzio parea fioco.\\
            Quando vidi costui nel gran diserto,\\
            «Miserere di me», gridai a lui,\\
            «qual che tu sii, od ombra od omo certo!».\\
            Rispuosemi: «Non omo, omo già fui,\\
            e li parenti miei furon lombardi,\\
            mantoani per patrïa ambedui.\\
            Nacqui sub Iulio, ancor che fosse tardi,\\
            e vissi a Roma sotto 'l buono Augusto\\
            nel tempo de li dèi falsi e bugiardi.\\
            Poeta fui, e cantai di quel giusto\\
            figliuol d'Anchise che venne di Troia,\\
            poi che 'l superbo Ilïón fu combusto.\\
            Ma tu perché ritorni a tanta noia?\\
            perché non sali il dilettoso monte\\
            ch'è principio e cagion di tutta gioia?».\\
            «Or se' tu quel Virgilio e quella fonte\\
            che spandi di parlar sì largo fiume?»,\\
            rispuos' io lui con vergognosa fronte.\\
            «O de li altri poeti onore e lume,\\
            vagliami 'l lungo studio e 'l grande amore\\
            che m'ha fatto cercar lo tuo volume.\\
            Tu se' lo mio maestro e 'l mio autore,\\
            tu se' solo colui da cu' io tolsi\\
            lo bello stilo che m'ha fatto onore.\\
            Vedi la bestia per cu' io mi volsi;\\
            aiutami da lei, famoso saggio,\\
            ch'ella mi fa tremar le vene e i polsi».\\
            «A te convien tenere altro vïaggio»,\\
            rispuose, poi che lagrimar mi vide,\\
            «se vuo' campar d'esto loco selvaggio;\\
            ché questa bestia, per la qual tu gride,\\
            non lascia altrui passar per la sua via,\\
            ma tanto lo 'mpedisce che l'uccide;\\
            e ha natura sì malvagia e ria,\\
            che mai non empie la bramosa voglia,\\
            e dopo 'l pasto ha più fame che pria.\\
            Molti son li animali a cui s'ammoglia,\\
            e più saranno ancora, infin che 'l veltro\\
            verrà, che la farà morir con doglia.\\
            Questi non ciberà terra né peltro,\\
            ma sapïenza, amore e virtute,\\
            e sua nazion sarà tra feltro e feltro.\\
            Di quella umile Italia fia salute\\
            per cui morì la vergine Cammilla,\\
            Eurialo e Turno e Niso di ferute.\\
            Questi la caccerà per ogne villa,\\
            fin che l'avrà rimessa ne lo 'nferno,\\
            là onde 'nvidia prima dipartilla.\\
            Ond' io per lo tuo me' penso e discerno\\
            che tu mi segui, e io sarò tua guida,\\
            e trarrotti di qui per loco etterno;\\
            ove udirai le disperate strida,\\
            vedrai li antichi spiriti dolenti,\\
            ch'a la seconda morte ciascun grida;\\
            e vederai color che son contenti\\
            nel foco, perché speran di venire\\
            quando che sia a le beate genti.\\
            A le quai poi se tu vorrai salire,\\
            anima fia a ciò più di me degna:\\
            con lei ti lascerò nel mio partire;\\
            ché quello imperador che là sù regna,\\
            perch' i' fu' ribellante a la sua legge,\\
            non vuol che 'n sua città per me si vegna.\\
            In tutte parti impera e quivi regge;\\
            quivi è la sua città e l'alto seggio:\\
            oh felice colui cu' ivi elegge!».\\
            E io a lui: «Poeta, io ti richeggio\\
            per quello Dio che tu non conoscesti,\\
            a ciò ch'io fugga questo male e peggio,\\
            che tu mi meni là dov' or dicesti,\\
            sì ch'io veggia la porta di san Pietro\\
            e color cui tu fai cotanto mesti».\\
            Allor si mosse, e io li tenni dietro.
        \end{patverse*}
    \end{verse}
    \switchcolumn  % added <<<<<
    \poemtitle{English}
    \settowidth{\versewidth}{Thou wouldst conduct me there where thou hast said,}\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
        \poemlines{3}
        \indentpattern{011}
        \begin{patverse*}
            MIDWAY upon the journey of our life\\
            I found myself within a forest dark,\\
            ⁠For the straightforward pathway had been lost.\\
            Ah me! how hard a thing it is to say\\
            ⁠What was this forest savage, rough, and stern, \\
            ⁠Which in the very thought renews the fear.\\
            So bitter is it, death is little more;\\
            ⁠But of the good to treat, which there I found,\\
            ⁠Speak will I of the other things I saw there.\\
            I cannot well repeat how there I entered, ⁠\\
            ⁠So full was I of slumber at the moment\\
            ⁠In which I had abandoned the true way.\\
            But after I had reached a mountain's foot,\\
            ⁠At that point where the valley terminated,\\
            ⁠Which had with consternation pierced my heart, ⁠\\
            Upward I looked, and I beheld its shoulders,\\
            ⁠Vested already with that planet's rays\\
            ⁠Which leadeth others right by every road.\\
            Then was the fear a little quieted\\
            ⁠That in my heart's lake had endured throughout ⁠\\
            ⁠The night, which I had passed so piteously.\\
            And even as he, who, with distressful breath,\\
            ⁠Forth issued from the sea upon the shore,\\
            ⁠Turns to the water perilous and gazes;\\
            So did my soul, that still was fleeing onward, \\
            ⁠Turn itself back to re-behold the pass\\
            ⁠Which never yet a living person left.\\
            After my weary body I had rested,\\
            ⁠The way resumed I on the desert slope,\\
            ⁠So that the firm foot ever was the lower. ⁠\\
            And lo! almost where the ascent began,\\
            ⁠A panther light and swift exceedingly,\\
            ⁠Which with a spotted skin was covered o'er!\\
            And never moved she from before my face,\\
            ⁠Nay, rather did impede so much my way, ⁠\\
            ⁠That many times I to return had turned.\\
            The time was the beginning of the morning,\\
            ⁠And up the sun was mounting with those stars\\
            ⁠That with him were, what time the Love Divine\\
            At first in motion set those beauteous things; ⁠\\
            ⁠So were to me occasion of good hope,\\
            ⁠The variegated skin of that wild beast,\\
            The hour of time, and the delicious season;\\
            ⁠But not so much, that did not give me fear\\
            ⁠A lion's aspect which appeared to me. ⁠\\
            He seemed as if against me he were coming\\
            ⁠With head uplifted, and with ravenous hunger,\\
            ⁠So that it seemed the air was afraid of him;\\
            And a she-wolf, that with all hungerings\\
            ⁠Seemed to be laden in her meagreness, ⁠\\
            ⁠And many folk has caused to live forlorn!\\
            She brought upon me so much heaviness,\\
            ⁠With the affright that from her aspect came,\\
            ⁠That I the hope relinquished of the height.\\
            And as he is who willingly acquires, \\
            ⁠And the time comes that causes him to lose,\\
            ⁠Who weeps in all his thoughts and is despondent,\\
            E'en such made me that beast withouten peace,\\
            ⁠Which, coming on against me by degrees,\\
            ⁠Thrust me back thither where the sun is silent. \\
            While I was rushing downward to the lowland,\\
            ⁠Before mine eyes did one present himself,\\
            ⁠Who seemed from long-continued silence hoarse.\\
            When I beheld him in the desert vast,\\
            ⁠"Have pity on me," unto him I cried, ⁠\\
            ⁠"Whiche'er thou art, or shade or real man!"\\
            He answered me: "Not man; man once I was,\\
            ⁠And both my parents were of Lombardy,\\
            ⁠And Mantuans by country both of them.\\
            Sub Julio was I born, though it was late, \\
            ⁠And lived at Rome under the good Augustus,\\
            ⁠During the time of false and lying gods.\\
            A Poet was I, and I sang that just\\
            ⁠Son of Anchises, who came forth from Troy,\\
            ⁠After that Ilion the superb was burned. \\
            But thou, why goest thou back to such annoyance?\\
            ⁠Why climb'st thou not the Mount Delectable,\\
            ⁠Which is the source and cause of every joy?"\\
            "Now, art thou that Virgilius and that fountain\\
            ⁠Which spreads abroad so wide a river of speech?" ⁠\\
            ⁠I made response to him with bashful forehead.\\
            "O, of the other poets honor and light,\\
            ⁠Avail me the long study and great love\\
            ⁠That have impelled me to explore thy volume!\\
            Thou art my master, and my author thou, ⁠\\
            ⁠Thou art alone the one from whom I took\\
            ⁠The beautiful style that has done honor to me.\\
            Behold the beast, for which I have turned back;\\
            ⁠Do thou protect me from her, famous Sage,\\
            ⁠For she doth make my veins and pulses tremble."\\
            "Thee it behoves to take another road,"\\
            ⁠Responded he, when he beheld me weeping,\\
            ⁠"If from this savage place thou wouldst escape;\\
            Because this beast, at which thou criest out,\\
            ⁠Suffers not any one to pass her way, ⁠\\
            ⁠But so doth harass him, that she destroys him;\\
            And has a nature so malign and ruthless,\\
            ⁠That never doth she glut her greedy will,\\
            ⁠And after food is hungrier than before.\\
            Many the animals with whom she weds, ⁠\\
            ⁠And more they shall be still, until the Greyhound\\
            ⁠Comes, who shall make her perish in her pain.\\
            He shall not feed on either earth or pelf,\\
            ⁠But upon wisdom, and on love and virtue;\\
            ⁠'Twixt Feltro and Feltro shall his nation be; ⁠\\
            Of that low Italy shall he be the saviour,\\
            ⁠On whose account the maid Camilla died,\\
            ⁠Euryalus, Turnus, Nisus, of their wounds;\\
            Through every city shall he hunt her down,\\
            ⁠Until he shall have driven her back to Hell, ⁠\\
            ⁠There from whence envy first did let her loose.\\
            Therefore I think and judge it for thy best\\
            ⁠Thou follow me, and I will be thy guide,\\
            ⁠And lead thee hence through the eternal place,\\
            Where thou shalt hear the desperate lamentations, \\
            ⁠Shalt see the ancient spirits disconsolate,\\
            ⁠Who cry out each one for the second death;\\
            And thou shalt see those who contented are\\
            ⁠Within the fire, because they hope to come,\\
            ⁠Whene'er it may be, to the blessed people; ⁠\\
            To whom, then, if thou wishest to ascend,\\
            ⁠A soul shall be for that than I more worthy;\\
            ⁠With her at my departure I will leave thee;\\
            Because that Emperor, who reigns above,\\
            ⁠In that I was rebellious to his law, ⁠\\
            ⁠Wills that through me none come into his city.\\
            He governs everywhere, and there he reigns;\\
            ⁠There is his city and his lofty throne;\\
            ⁠O happy he whom thereto he elects!"\\
            And I to him: "Poet, I thee entreat, ⁠\\
            ⁠By that same God whom thou didst never know,\\
            ⁠So that I may escape this woe and worse,\\
            Thou wouldst conduct me there where thou hast said,\\
            ⁠That I may see the portal of Saint Peter,\\
            ⁠And those thou makest so disconsolate." ⁠\\
            Then he moved on, and I behind him followed.    \end{patverse*}
    \end{verse}
    \switchcolumn % added <<<<<
    %Ligurian
    \poemtitle{Ligurian}
    \settowidth{\versewidth}{ò ammiòu sciù in èrto e ò visto allôa e sêu spalle}\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
        \poemlines{3}
        \indentpattern{011}
        \begin{patverse*}
            A-o mëzo do cammin da nòstra vitta\\
            me so' attrovòu inte na forèsta scüa,\\
            perdendo a strâ che a-o ben l'òmmo a tragitta.\\
            Quanto, a dî comme a l'ëa, l'è còsa düa,\\
            sta forèsta sarvæga e àspia e fòrte,\\
            che a ripensâla ancon poïa a me procüa\\
            Tanto a l'è amäa che no goæi ciù l'è a mòrte\\
            ma, pe trattâ do ben che gh'ò attrovòu,\\
            de l'âtro ò visto e l'è ben che ô ripòrte.\\
            Mi no sò ben dî comme ghe so' intròu,\\
            tanto mi ëo pin de seunno in quòu momento\\
            che o vëo cammin avéivo abbandonòu.\\
            Ma quande a-i pê de na montâ a gran stento\\
            mi so' arrivòu, dove finiva a valle\\
            che into chêu a m'aiva misso un gran spavento,\\
            ò ammiòu sciù in èrto e ò visto allôa e sêu spalle\\
            dezzâ vestïe di raggi do pianeta\\
            che o guidda drïto e o fâ che no se falle.\\
            Allôa s'è fæto a poïa un pö ciù queta,\\
            che into lago do chêu a m'ëa düâ\\
            a-a neutte che a l'ëa stæta coscì inquieta.\\
            E comme chi con fadiga affannâ,\\
            sciortïo de fëua da-o mâ gròsso insce a riva\\
            l'ægua peigosa o se regïa li a ammiâ,\\
            coscì l'animo mæ, che anco' o corriva,\\
            o s'è regiòu inderrê a ammiâ quello passo\\
            che o no l'à mai lasciòu personn-a viva.\\
            Dòppo ësime pôsòu da-o gran strapasso,\\
            ò repiggiòu a montâ a riva desèrta,\\
            coscì che àivo o pê fèrmo sempre in basso.\\
            Quande, a-o prinçipio da montâ ò scovèrta\\
            na lonza lëgia e bèll'e pronta a-a caccia,\\
            che de péi tùtto a macce a l'ëa covèrta;\\
            e a no voéiva scostâse da-a mæ faccia,\\
            ansi, a impediva tanto o mæ cammin,\\
            che m'ëo za giòu pe tornâ insce a mæ traccia.\\
            L'ëa o tempo insce o prinçipio do mattin,\\
            e o sô o montava sciù con quelle stelle\\
            che i l'ëan con lê quande l'Amô divin\\
            o l'à inissiòu a mesciâ quæ còse bèlle;\\
            coscì che a ben sperâ àivo raxon\\
            de quella fëa con tùtte e macce a-a pelle\\
            da l'ôa do tempo e da-a dôçe stagion;\\
            ma no coscì che poïa a no me desse\\
            a brùtta vista che ò avüo de un leon.\\
            Me pàiva contra a mì che o se mescesse\\
            con a testa äta e tanta raggia e famme,\\
            che pàiva che anche l'äia a ne tremmesse.\\
            E 'na lôa ò visto tùtta òsse e pellamme,\\
            d'ògni coæ càrega inta sêu magressa,\\
            che tanta gente a l'à fæto stâ gramme;\\
            questa a m'à dæto li tanta amaressa\\
            con a poïa che a sciortiva da-a sêu vista,\\
            che ò perso a speànsa de montâ in altessa.\\
            E comme un che, fæta 'na conquista,\\
            vegne o tempo ch'o a pèrde e o se despiaxe,\\
            e in tùtti i sêu penscëi o se rattrista;\\
            pægio m'à fæto a bestia sensa paxe,\\
            che, vegnindome incontro, a me sponciava\\
            cianin cianin lazzù dove o sô o taxe.\\
            Intanto che zù in basso mi derruava,\\
            davanti a-i euggi me se gh'è li òffèrto\\
            chi pe-o silensio röco o o se mostrava\\
            Quande l'ò visto inte quòu gran desèrto,\\
            "Miserere de mì", criando gh'ò fæto,\\
            "che ti seggi 'n'ombra ò 'n òmmo çèrto!"\\
            "No son un òmmo, ma òmmo son stæto",\\
            o m'à dïto, "e i mæ pænti i l'ëan lombardi,\\
            e a l'è Màntoa che a nascion a gh'à dæto.\\
            Nasciüo sub Julio, anche se un pö tardi,\\
            son visciüo a Romma sotto o bon Augusto\\
            a-o tempo che gh'ëa i dèi fäsi e boxardi\\
            Son stæto un poeta, e ò cantòu quello giusto\\
            figgio d'Anchise vegnüo via da Tròia,\\
            dòppo che a l'ëa brüxâ inte 'n gran trambusto.\\
            Ma ti perchè ti torni a tanta nòia,\\
            e no ti væ insce o mäveggiôso monte\\
            che o l'è prinçipio e caxon de ògni giòia?"\\
            "T'è pròpio ti o Virgiglio e quella fonte\\
            che de parlâ ti spandi un largo sciumme?",\\
            gh'ò rispòsto con vergognôsa fronte.\\
            "Ti che ti è di ätri poeti ònô e lumme,\\
            conscìdera o gran studdio e o grande amô\\
            che o m'à fæto riçercâ o têu volumme.\\
            Ti ti è o mæ méistro, ti ti è o mæ autô,\\
            ti è sôlo ti quello da-o quæ ò piggiòu\\
            quòu bèllo stile che o m'à fæto ònô.\\
            Ammïa a bestia pe-a quæ me son regiòu;\\
            aggiùttime, sävio degno de òmàggio,\\
            che pe lê e venn-e e i pösi i m'an tremmòu."\\
            "A ti convegne tegnî 'n ätro viaggio",\\
            ò fà a mì che cianzéivo a tésta bassa,\\
            "se t'êu scampâ da sto grammo passaggio;\\
            perchè t'æ da savéi che sta bestiassa\\
            nisciun a lascia passâ pe-a sêu strâ,\\
            ma tanto a l'impedisce che a l'ammassa;\\
            e a l'à in sè 'na natüa coscì despiâ,\\
            cha a no soddisfa mai a sêu coæ bramosa,\\
            e dòppo avéi mangiòu a no è mai soulâ.\\
            Tante so' e bestie co-e quæ lê a se sposa,\\
            e ciù tante i saiàn, fin quande un vèltro\\
            vegnâ a dâghe 'na mòrte dolorosa.\\
            Questo o no se nutriâ de tæra ò pèltro\\
            ma de virtù, de sæximo e d'amô,\\
            e a nascion o l'aviâ tra fèltro e fèltro.\\
            De quell'Itaglia o saiâ o salvatô\\
            pe-a quæ l'è mòrta a vèrgine Camilla,\\
            e Eurialo e Turno e Niso, con valô.\\
            Questo o ghe daiâ a caccia pe ògni villa,\\
            finchè o l'aviâ rimissa inte l'infèrno,\\
            donde inviddia a partî gh'à allentòu a brilla.\\
            Pe-o têu bén questo allôa mi penso e çèrno\\
            che ti me segui, fàndote guiddâ,\\
            pe portâte da chi inte un pòsto etèrno\\
            dove i despiæ ti î sentiæ cianze e luâ,\\
            e ti veddiæ i spïti antighi dolénti\\
            che a 'na segonda mòrte i stan a criâ;\\
            e di ätri ti veddiæ che i stan contenti\\
            into feugo, sperando de vegnî\\
            ò primma ò dòppo fra e beate genti.\\
            Se pòi a montâ ciù in sciù t'êu proseguî,\\
            'n'ànima ghe saiâ de mì ciù degna:\\
            con lê mì te lasciö into mæ partî;\\
            perchè l'imperatô che lasciù o regna,\\
            essendo stæto ribèlle a-a sêu lezze,\\
            che pòsse intrâ inta sêu çittæ o disdegna.\\
            Dappertùtto o l'impera e anche là o rezze;\\
            lasciù gh'è a sêu çittæ e l'äto scanno:\\
            òh feliçe chi a stâ con lê o l'elezze!"\\
            E a lê: "Poeta", diggo pin d'affanno,\\
            "pe-o Dio da ti no conosciüo te invito,\\
            perchè da-o mâ me scampe e da ògni danno,\\
            a portâme con ti dove t'æ dïto,\\
            coscì che vedde a pòrta de San Pê\\
            e quelli che en despiæ inte un tristo scito."\\
            Lê o s'è mesciòu, e ghe so' andæto derrê.
        \end{patverse*}
    \end{verse}
    \switchcolumn % added <<<<<
    \poemtitle{Portuguese}
    \settowidth{\versewidth}{“Quem quer que sejas, sombra ou homem certo!”}\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
        \poemlines{3}
        \indentpattern{011}
        \begin{patverse*}
            Da nossa vida, em meio da jornada,\\
            Achei-me numa selva tenebrosa,\\
            Tendo perdido a verdadeira estrada.\\
            Dizer qual era é cousa tão penosa,\\
            Desta brava espessura a asperidade,\\
            Que a memória a relembra inda cuidosa.\\
            Na morte há pouco mais de acerbidade;\\
            Mas para o bem narrar lá deparado\\
            De outras cousas que vi, direi verdade.\\
            Contar não posso como tinha entrado;\\
            Tanto o sono os sentidos me tomara,\\
            Quando hei o bom caminho abandonado.\\
            Depois que a uma colina me cercara,\\
            Onde ia o vale escuro terminando,\\
            Que pavor tão profundo me causara.\\
            Ao alto olhei, e já, de luz banhando,\\
            Vi-lhe estar às espaldas o planeta,\\
            Que, certo, em toda parte vai guiando.\\
            Então o assombro um tanto se aquieta,\\
            Que do peito no lago perdurava,\\
            Naquela noite atribulada, inquieta.\\
            E como quem o anélito esgotava\\
            Sobre as ondas, já salvo, inda medroso\\
            Olha o mar perigoso em que lutava,\\
            O meu ânimo assim, que treme ansioso,\\
            Volveu-se a remirar vencido o espaço\\
            Que homem vivo jamais passou ditoso.\\
            Tendo já repousado o corpo lasso,\\
            Segui pela deserta falda avante;\\
            Mais baixo sendo o pé firme no passo.\\
            Eis da subida quase ao mesmo instante\\
            Assoma ágil e rápida pantera\\
            Tendo a pele por malhas cambiante.\\
            Não se afastava de ante mim a fera;\\
            E em modo tal meu caminhar tolhia,\\
            Que atrás por vezes eu tornar quisera.\\
            No céu a aurora já resplandecia,\\
            Subia o sol, dos astros rodeado,\\
            Seus sócios, quando o Amor divino um dia\\
            A tais primores movimento há dado.\\
            Me infundiam desta arte alma esperança\\
            Da fera o dorso alegre e mosqueado,\\
            A hora amena e a quadra doce e mansa.\\
            De um leão de repente surge o aspecto,\\
            Que ao meu peito o pavor de novo lança.\\
            Que me investisse então cuido inquieto;\\
            Com fome e raiva atroz fronte levanta;\\
            Tremer parece o ar ao seu conspeto.\\
            Eis surge loba, que de magra espanta;\\
            De ambições todas parecia cheia;\\
            Foi causa a muitos de miséria tanta!\\
            Com tanta intensa torvação me enleia\\
            Pelo terror, que o cenho seu movia,\\
            Que a mente à altura não subir receia.\\
            Como quem lucro anela noite e dia,\\
            Se acaso o tempo de perder lhe chega,\\
            Rebenta em pranto e triste se excrucia.\\
            A fera assim me fez, que não sossega;\\
            Pouco a pouco me investe até lançar-me\\
            Lá onde o sol se cala e a luz me nega.\\
            Quando ao vale eu já ia baquear-me\\
            Alguém fraco de voz diviso perto,\\
            Que após largo silêncio quer falar-me.\\
            Tanto que o vejo nesse grão deserto,\\
            — “Tem compaixão de mim” — bradei transido —\\
            “Quem quer que sejas, sombra ou homem certo!”\\
            “Homem não sou” tornou-me — “mas hei sido,\\
            Pais lombardos eu tive; sempre amada\\
            Mântua lhes foi; haviam lá nascido.\\
            “Nasci de Júlio em era retardada,\\
            Vivi em Roma sob o bom Augusto,\\
            Quando em deuses havia a crença errada.\\
            “Poeta, decantei feitos do justo\\
            Filho de Anquíses, que de Tróia veio,\\
            Depois que Ílion soberbo foi combusto.\\
            “Mas por que tornas da tristeza ao meio?\\
            Por que não vais ao deleitoso monte,\\
            Que o prazer todo encerra no seu seio?”\\
            “— Oh! Virgílio, tu és aquela fonte\\
            Donde em rio caudal brota a eloqüência?”\\
            Falei, curvando vergonhoso a fronte. —\\
            “Ó dos poetas lustre, honra, eminência!\\
            Valham-me o longo estudo, o amor profundo\\
            Com que em teu livro procurei ciência!\\
            “És meu mestre, o modelo sem segundo;\\
            Unicamente és tu que hás-me ensinado;\\
            O belo estilo que honra-me no mundo.\\
            “A fera vês que o passo me há vedado;\\
            Sábio famoso, acude ao perseguido!\\
            Tremo no pulso e veias, transtornado!”\\
            Respondeu, do meu pranto condoído;\\
            “Te convém outra rota de ora avante\\
            Para o lugar selvagem ser vencido.\\
            “A fera, que te faz bradar tremante,\\
            Aqui passar não deixa impunemente;\\
            Tanto se opõe, que mata o caminhante.\\
            “Tem tão má natureza, é tão furente,\\
            Que os apetites seus jamais sacia,\\
            E fome, impando, mais que de antes sente.\\
            “Com muitos animais se consorcia,\\
            Há-de a outros se unir té ser chegado\\
            Lebréu, que a leve à hórrida agonia.\\
            “Por ouro ou por poder nunca tentado\\
            Saber, virtude, amor terá por norte,\\
            Sendo entre Feltro e Feltro potentado.\\
            “Será da humilde Itália amparo forte,\\
            Por quem Camila a virgem dera a vida,\\
            Turno Eurialo, Niso acharam morte.\\
            “Por ele, em toda parte, repelida\\
            Irá lançar-se no infernal assento,\\
            Donde foi pela Inveja conduzida.\\
            “Agora, por teu prol, eu tenho o intento\\
            De levar-te comigo; ir-te-ei guiando\\
            Pela estância do eterno sofrimento,\\
            “Onde, estridentes gritos escutando,\\
            Verás almas antigas em tortura\\
            Segunda morte a brados suplicando.\\
            “Outros ledos verás, que, em prova dura\\
            Das chamas, inda esperam ter o gozo\\
            De Deus no prêmio da imortal ventura.\\
            “Se lá subir quiseres, um ditoso\\
            Espírito, melhor te será guia,\\
            Quando eu deixar-te, ao reino glorioso.\\
            “Do céu o Imperador, a rebeldia\\
            Minha à lei castigando, não consente\\
            Que eu da cidade sua haja a alegria.\\
            “Em toda parte impera onipotente,\\
            Mas tem no Empíreo sua augusta sede:\\
            Feliz, por ele, o eleito à glória ingente!”\\
            — “Vate, rogo-te” — eu disse — “me concede,\\
            Por esse Deus, que nunca hás conhecido,\\
            Porque este e maior mal de mim se arrede.\\
            “Que, até onde disseste conduzido,\\
            À porta de São Pedro eu vá contigo\\
            E veja os maus que houveste referido”.\\
            Move-se o Vate então, após o sigo.
        \end{patverse*}
    \end{verse}
\end{paracol}   
    
\end{document}
```